# Adding a default value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group text-left">
                            <p class="text-left">@DbRes.T("Water quality parameter:", "Resources")</p>
                            <select class="form-control" name="parameters" id="riverWaterQualityParameterSelect">
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

which I populate on page load like so

```
 public ActionResult GetParametersCountSamplesForStation(int stationId)
        {
            var stationTypeId = _stationRepository.GetDetailsForStation(stationId).TypeId;
            List<StationParameterDTO> stationPrametersSamplesCount = _stationRepository.GetParametersCountSamplesForStation(stationId, stationTypeId);
            var stationAccess = getUserStationTypeAcccess().Result;
            string stationType = _stationRepository.GetDetailsForStation(stationId).Type;
            var canAccess = stationAccess.Contains(stationType);
            return Json(new { data = stationPrametersSamplesCount, canAccessActions = canAccess });
        }
```

I get all the values in `stationPrametersSamplesCount` which are in the database.
I'd like a add an additional value in the dropdown which is not and cannot be in the database. I'd like to add an `all` value which will be selected by default. Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: So push a new item onto the list

Comment: In a <select> the first value is the default.

Comment: [This page](https://javascript.info/modifying-document) gives a good introduction on how to insert elements on the page